# Format Sequelize API Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sequelize.js

I'm using NodeJS and Sequelize to pull data from a Postgres DB. Attempting to make my response match this:

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Emma Smith",
            "avatar": "avatars/300-6.jpg",
            "email": "smith@kpmg.com",
            "position": "Art Director",
            "role": "Administrator",
            "last_login": "Yesterday",
            "two_steps": false,
            "joined_day": "10 Nov 2022, 9:23 pm",
            "online": false
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Melody Macy",
            "initials": {
                "label": "M",
                "state": "danger"
            },
            "email": "melody@altbox.com",
            "position": "Marketing Analytic",
            "role": "Analyst",
            "last_login": "20 mins ago",
            "two_steps": true,
            "joined_day": "10 Nov 2022, 8:43 pm",
            "online": false
       
        }
    ],
    "payload": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "first_page_url": "/?page=1",
            "from": 1,
            "last_page": 3,
            "links": [
                {
                    "url": null,
                    "label": "&laquo; Previous",
                    "active": false,
                    "page": null
                },
                {
                    "url": "/?page=1",
                    "label": "1",
                    "active": true,
                    "page": 1
                },
                {
                    "url": "/?page=2",
                    "label": "2",
                    "active": false,
                    "page": 2
                },
                {
                    "url": "/?page=3",
                    "label": "3",
                    "active": false,
                    "page": 3
                },
                {
                    "url": "/?page=2",
                    "label": "Next &raquo;",
                    "active": false,
                    "page": 2
                }
            ],
            "next_page_url": "/?page=2",
            "items_per_page": 10,
            "prev_page_url": null,
            "to": 10,
            "total": 21
        }
    }
}
```

Currently my output is:

```json
{
    "totalItems": 31,
    "cases": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Emma Smith",
            "avatar": "avatars/300-6.jpg",
            "email": "smith@kpmg.com",
            "position": "Art Director",
            "role": "Administrator",
            "last_login": "Yesterday",
            "two_steps": false,
            "joined_day": "10 Nov 2022, 9:23 pm",
            "online": false
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Melody Macy",
            "initials": {
                "label": "M",
                "state": "danger"
            },
            "email": "melody@altbox.com",
            "position": "Marketing Analytic",
            "role": "Analyst",
            "last_login": "20 mins ago",
            "two_steps": true,
            "joined_day": "10 Nov 2022, 8:43 pm",
            "online": false
       
        }
        
    ],
    "totalPages": 4,
    "currentPage": 1
}
```

With a controller file of:

```
const db = require("../models");
const Cases = db.cases;
const Op = db.Sequelize.Op;

const getPagination = (page, size) => {
  const limit = size ? +size : 10;
  const offset = page ? page * limit : 0;

  return { limit, offset };
};

const getPagingData = (data, page, limit) => {
  const { count: totalItems, rows: cases } = data;
  const currentPage = page ? +page : 1;
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / limit);


  return { totalItems, cases, totalPages, currentPage };
};


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Retrieve all Cases from the database.

exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
const { page, size, title } = req.query;
var condition = title ? { title: { [Op.like]: `%${title}%` } } : null;



const { limit, offset } = getPagination(page, size);

Cases.findAndCountAll({ where: condition, limit, offset })
  .then(data => {
    const response= getPagingData(data, page, limit);
    res.send(response);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message:
        err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving cases."
    });
  });
};



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// Create and Save a new Cases
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  // Validate request
  if (!req.body.case_name) {
    res.status(400).send({
      message: "Content can not be empty!"
    });
    return;
  }

  // Create a Cases
  const cases = {
    name: req.body.name,
    avatar: req.body.avatar,
    email: req.body.email,
    position: req.body.position,
    role: req.body.role,
    last_login: req.body.last_login,
    two_steps: req.body.two_steps,
    joined_day: req.body.joined_day,
    online: req.body.online
  };

  // Save Cases in the database
  Cases.create(cases)
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Case."
      });
    });
};


// Find a single Cases with an id
exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  Cases.findByPk(id)
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: "Error retrieving Cases with id=" + id
      });
    });
};

// Update a Cases by the id in the request
exports.update = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  Cases.update(req.body, {
    where: { id: id }
  })
    .then(num => {
      if (num == 1) {
        res.send({
          message: "Cases was updated successfully."
        });
      } else {
        res.send({
          message: `Cannot update Cases with id=${id}. Maybe Cases was not found or req.body is empty!`
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: "Error updating Cases with id=" + id
      });
    });
};

// Delete a Cases with the specified id in the request
exports.delete = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  Cases.destroy({
    where: { id: id }
  })
    .then(num => {
      if (num == 1) {
        res.send({
          message: "Cases was deleted successfully!"
        });
      } else {
        res.send({
          message: `Cannot delete Cases with id=${id}. Maybe Cases was not found!`
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: "Could not delete Cases with id=" + id
      });
    });
};

// Delete all Casess from the database.
exports.deleteAll = (req, res) => {
  Cases.destroy({
    where: {},
    truncate: false
  })
    .then(nums => {
      res.send({ message: `${nums} Casess were deleted successfully!` });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while removing all Casess."
      });
    });
};

// find all published Cases
exports.findAllPublished = (req, res) => {
  const { page, size } = req.query;
  const { limit, offset } = getPagination(page, size);

  Cases.findAndCountAll({ where: { published: true }, limit, offset })
    .then(data => {
      const response = getPagingData(data, page, limit);
      res.send(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving Casess."
      });
    });
};
```

Attempted various ways of formatting the output to JSON using both built in methods of Sequalize and also using middleware to covert the output to JSON. Is there an easy way to change the formatting to the response I'm looking for?